# xslt - removing quotes, single quotes, <, >, \, / using the replace function

Tags: replace, xslt-2.0

I have tried to look at previous answers, but it is not clear to me.  I would like to use the replace function to replace various characters that are causing me issues during saxon tranformation.
My code fragment is:

```
rdfs:comment "<xsl:value-of select="replace(DDTEXT, '[&quot;]|[&apos;]|[\\]|[\/]|[&lt;]|[&gt;]', '')"/>" ;
```

Saxon gives me the error: 
XPST0003: XPath syntax error at char 23 on line 66 in {replace(DDTEXT, '["]|[']|}:expected ")", found "]"

I have spent several hours on this already... Any help appreciated.  I am using xslt2, and have tried my regex using rubular, but I guess that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[&amp;quot;]|[&amp;apos;]|[\\]|[/]|[&amp;lt;]|[&amp;gt;]', '')"/>
```

Comment: nope, that did not work for me.  I ended up replacing these values with their escaped URL values.